# How to use AWS Powershell to tag the VPC peering links

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using PowerShell to create VPC peering links. It doesn't look like AWS Powershell supports tagging the peering links. Can someone confirm?

If it is possible to tag the peering link using PowerShell, what is the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
PS C:\>$tag = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag
PS C:\>$tag.Key = "myTag"
PS C:\>$tag.Value = "myTagValue"

PS C:\>New-EC2Tag -Resource pcx-abcd1234 -Tag $tag
```

Reference: [`New-EC2Tag` Cmdlet documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-EC2Tag.html)

Yes, `New-EC2Tag` works fine on VPC resources.